# How to fix MSBuild error NU1607: Version conflict detected?

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget-package-restore

My Web API .Net Core 2.2 project is built with no errors in VS 2019. However, when I try to build it in TFS 2018 build server, the following error occurs in NuGet Restore step:

`NU1607: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions. Reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue.
MyWebAPIProject (>= 1.0.0) -> NLog.Web.AspNetCore (>= 4.8.6) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions (>= 2.1.1)
 MyWebAPIProject (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App (>= 2.1.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions (>= 2.1.0).`

I added Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions ver 2.2.0 NuGet package to MyWebAPIProject. Now, MyWebAPIProject.cproj file looks something like this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <!--<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>-->

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>%24/MyWebAPIProject</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>{AAAAAAA-AAA-AAA-AAA-AAA}</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>http://TFSBuildServer:8080/tfs/defaultcollection</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>.</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <UserSecretsId>adfbcb24-c16e-40ec-bf0a-45b437155743</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Schema" Version="4.6.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.8.6" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyWebAPI.Repository\MyWebAPI.Repository.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyWebAPI.Interfaces\MyWebAPI.Interfaces.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>`
```

But, MSBuild still fails with the same error. Can anyone please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My project TFS build step 'Use Nuget x.x.x' was configured to use 4.3.0 version. The 4.3.0 is a default version when a new TFS build is created. I changed the NuGet.exe version to 4.6.0 in *Version of NuGet.exe to install* box to make it the same as it was shown in my VS 2017 Help/About window for NuGet Package Manager. The version conflict had gone after that. However, when I set NuGetexe version up to 5.3.1 like in my VS2019, the errors related to dotnet sdk 3.0 popped up. So, I changed the version back to 4.6.0.